# How to create and zip multiple files together and download them using Django and Python 3

Tags: python, django, django-views, httpresponse, zip

In my django app I create two text files and I want them to download automatically when a form is submitted. I believe that in order to do this I need to zip the files together, and then download the zip file. I am using the zipfile module to do this.

Here is my code in the views.py file.

```
with open('file1.txt', 'w') as file_1:
    numbers = ['1', '2', '3']
    for num in numbers:
        file_1.write(num)
        file_2.write('\n')

with open('file2.txt', 'w') as file_2:
    letters = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    for letter in letters:
        file_1.write(letter)
        file_2.write('\n')

comp_file = ZipFile('My_Files.zip', 'w')
comp_file.write('file1.txt', compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
comp_file.write('file2.txt', compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
comp_file.close()

return HttpResponse(content_type='application/zip', headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="My_Files.zip"'})
```

My expected output would be a zip file that could be extracted to contain the file1.txt and file2.txt. However, the output I actually get is a zip file that can't be extracted because it is empty.

Also, this method actually creates all of the files in my working directory, which I don't really want to do. Does anyone know how I can do this without actually saving the files in my own directory? My current plan is to just delete the files after they are downloaded by the user.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Looking at the [HttpResponse Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment) makes me think that this:

```
return HttpResponse(content_type='application/zip', headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="My_Files.zip"'})
```

Should really be this:

```
return HttpResponse(comp_file, content_type='application/zip', headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="My_Files.zip"'})
```

However, the output is still an empty zip file.

Comment: Pass the file handle to `HttpResponse`, just setting `filename="My_Files.zip"` will not do anything.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat by this do you mean something like this?
`return HttpResponse(comp_file, content_type='application/zip', headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="My_Files.zip"'})`
I did try this, but got the same issue- it just downloads an empty zip file.

Answer (score 0):

this case can be the zip file is already close. So the downloaded zip file is empty. So the code can be like this.

```py
...
comp_file = ZipFile('My_Files.zip', 'w')
comp_file.write('file1.txt', compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
comp_file.write('file2.txt', compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
return HttpResponse(comp_file, content_type='application/zip', headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="My_Files.zip"'})
```